# Fibonacci numbers $F_{n+3} + F_{n} = 2F_{n+2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

Prove $F_{n+3} + F_{n} = 2F_{n+2}$ for any positive integer n.

So What I did was this:

fn+ fn+1 = fn+2

fn + fn+1 = fn+2 => fn+2 -fn+1
fn+1 + fn+2 = fn+3

then I subsituted into equation in question and got:

fn+2-fn+fn+2=fn+3=fn+3 + fn=2n+2

So that makes sense. But I am having trouble grasping why this proves to be true for any integer.

Comment: Is it $2f_n+2$ or $2f_{n+2}?$

Comment: The second one.

Comment: The logic of the argument is not at all clear. And there are typos. Clearer would be $f_{n+3}=f_{n+2}+f_{n+1}$. Therefore $f_{n+3}+f_n=f_{n+2}+f_{n+1}+f_n=f_{n+2}+f_{n+2}$. I would advise, when you are *writing up* a proof, **never** to work backwards from the desired expression to something that looks true.

Answer (score 3):

For all $n$, $f_n+f_{n+1}=f_{n+2}$ (Fibonacci numbers). For this reason, $f_{n+1}+f_{n+2}=f_{n+3}.$

So, $f_n+(f_{n+1}+f_{n+2})=f_n+f_{n+3}$, and $(f_n+f_{n+1})+f_{n+2}=2f_{n+2}.$

Comment: How did you go from the first equation on the bottom line to the second one?

Comment: $$f_n + \color{blue}{f_{n+3}} = f_n + \color{blue}{(f_{n+1} + f_{n+2})} = \color{red}{(f_n + f_{n+1})} + f_{n+2} = \color{red}{f_{n+2}} + f_{n+2} = 2f_{n+2}.$$

Comment: @Charles: observe the parenthesis.